# SQL - Sum values when there is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
RowID Column1 Column2
1       3       2
2       5       2
3       2       9
4       5      NULL
5       8      NULL
6       9       3
7       1      NULL
```

I need first row of Column1 to Sum every time there is a NULL value in Column2. And it would continue the logic down the rows.
So, the result should look like:

```
RowID Column1 Column2
1       3       2
2       5       2
3       15      9
4       5      NULL
5       8      NULL
6       10      3
7       1      NULL
```

Notice Row 3 summed 2+5+8 =15 and Row 6 summed 9+1 =10. So, basically the row prior to Null value in Column2 summed the values in column1 until there was no more NULL values in column2. Then it resumed in row 6 where the next value was NULL.

Comment: Look at window functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it. I have set up the data in a table variable for demo.

```
declare @t table(RowID int, C1 int, C2 int)
insert @t values (1, 3, 2)
,(2, 5, 2)
,(3, 2, 9)
,(4, 5, NULL)
,(5, 8, NULL)
,(6, 9, 3)
,(7, 1, NULL)

select RowID, sum(C1), max(C2)
from (
select RowID, C1, C2 from @t  
union all
select T1.RowID, T2.C1, null
from @t t1
join @t t2 on t2.RowID>t1.RowID and t2.C2 is null
    and not exists(
        select * from @t t3 
        where t3.RowID>t1.RowID and t3.c2 is not null and t3.RowID<t2.RowID
        )
where T1.C2 is not null
) q group by RowID
```

Result:

```
RowID   C1  C2
1       3   2
2       5   2
3       15  9
4       5   NULL
5       8   NULL
6       10  3
7       1   NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. Really appreciated!

Comment: There is a little problem with the code. It ignores the duplicate values under C1. So, if C1 is 2, 5, 5 it should return 12 but it returns 7.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  You need to look at the rows in reverse order, assigning the `NULL` values to the value before them.

The idea is to assign a group to the rows to sum.  This is the number of non-`NULL` values following the row.  With this, you can then use a window function to aggregate:

```
select t.*,
       (case when c2 is null then c1
             else sum(c1) over (partition by grp)
        end) as new_c1
from (select t.*, count(c2) over (order by rowid rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as grp
      from t
     ) t
order by rowid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=96ee3a8ce02eabaa6fdf9478bf340a18) is a db<>fiddle.